# How can I allow non-administrators to use shutdown.exe?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, windows-task-scheduler

As per the comments in the accepted answer to [this](https://superuser.com/q/330858/55611) question, I'm having issues running a scheduled task which calls `shutdown.exe`, even when the user is an administrator. I'm administrating someone else's machine using their main account, so I can't exactly change too much as they like things the way that they are.

What's really strange is that I can only make the task run if:

1. The user is an administrator.
2. They have defined a password.

For some strange reason unknown to me, not only does a user have to be an administrator, but they also *must* have a password on the account in order for the scheduled task to run. Otherwise, I get access denied errors and the task fails to run.

How can I make this work without having to force the user to define a password for their account?

Essentially, the remaining goal is to have the computer shut down (no matter who is or is not logged in) at 11pm every night.

I run into the following errors below when I try to set the task in the `Scheduled Tasks` program:

[image]

> An error has occurred while attempting to set task account information. 
>   The specific error is: 
>   0x8007005: Access is denied. 
>   You do not have permission to perform the requested operation.

For the record, here's my security policy, you can see that my user has the permission to force shutdown and manually shutdown the computer:

[image]

Comment: Is the scheduled task running on the machine you want to shut down, or remotely?  Have you tried using psshutdown instead of shutdown?

Comment: Locally, haven't tried psshutdown.

Comment: Windows requires a password for remote desktop and other network administration operations because it'd just be too big of a security hole to have it any other way.  On top of that, many people would first blame Microsoft's poor security rather than their own negligence if they were hacked.

Comment: Hmm. Well, Linux is normally pretty secure, and I can simply `sudo crontab -e` and add `0 23 * * * shutdown -P now`. What could possibly be so hard for an administrator account on Windows to shut down the computer at a given time each day?

Comment: Unix *root* has absolute control. Windows *Administrators* do not; only *SYSTEM* does. (As you can see in your own screenshot, many privileges are assigned to Administrators just like a normal group, and can be revoked.) In a sense, Windows can be *more* secure -- most of its insecurity is caused by software bugs and by "first user is an administrator" default settings in XP and older.

Comment: @grawity: I don't think SYSTEM can hold any rights in the network domain. That just reinforces your conclusion: The Windows NT security model is safer (more robust) precisely because it's harder to gain all rights. Unix _root_ is far too convenient, hence _sudo_

Comment: @MSalters: No, it [cannot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684190%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but a Domain Admin, like Administrator, has sufficient privileges to elevate themselves to SYSTEM when necessary, and domain-wide admin privileges cannot be revoked as easily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to configure said scheduled task to run under an Administrator account. You do *not* need to use the same account as the usually-logged-on user – simply provide different credentials when creating the task.

If you do not want "Administrator" to have a password, you could just create a dedicated account just for the scheduled task. (A limited User account will work as well, if you apply the fix below.)

---

The `shutdown.exe` program needs *SeRemoteShutdownPrivilege* to run, instead of the usual *SeShutdownPrivilege* – my guess is that it uses the same RPC for shutting down both local and remote machines. (This would explain the need for a password, too – by default, only console logins are exempt, which obviously does not include RPC.)

You can grant *SeRemoteShutdownPrivilege* through `secpol.msc` → *Local Policies* → *User Rights Assignment*, by editing the "Force shutdown from remote system" entry.

- You can create a dedicated account for the task and add it here (best choice).
- For interactive command-line usage by any user, you can add `INTERACTIVE`.
- For scheduled tasks by any user, add `BATCH`.

Comment: +1: dedicated account for scheduled task.  GREAT answer.

Comment: I tried to allow my user to do this by enabling `INTERACTIVE`, `BATCH`, and my user for that privilege, and now Windows won't get past the "welcome" screen, it just hangs :(

Comment: @TK: Strange, as the Welcome screen does not *use* that privilege for anything. Try logging in as another user, or through Safe Mode. If you manage to get in, check Event Log (`eventvwr.msc`).

Comment: I can't get into any account. The welcome screen is displayed and nothing else. I have no visible options.

Comment: @TK: Even in safe mode? Also, try pressing Ctrl+Alt+Del twice on the welcome screen.

Comment: Better, it boots now. However, it's still not working, see edit on question.

Comment: @TK: Rather unusual. I'd try checking with Process Monitor what *exactly* is returning "Access denied"...

Comment: +1 This helped to solve a 'Using Windows Server 2012 as a workstation' problem. _How do I turn off the computer as a user rather than an administrator?_ By adding the Users group to the 'Shut down the system' right!

Answer (score 2):

This is an easier solution:

If you want to allow only local users to run `%windir%\system32\shutdown.exe -s -t 0`, grant the `SeRemoteShutdownPrivilege` to the group `INTERACTIVE`. Only local users are members of this group.

How to do it: Run `secpol.msc`. Open `Security Settings \ Local Policies \ User Rights Assignment`.  Double-click `Force shutdown from a remote system` in the right pane.  Click `Add User or Group`. Enter the name `INTERACTIVE` in the text box and click `Check names`, then click `OK`, and `OK` again.

Source: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/aaron_margosis/archive/2006/01/27/518214.aspx

Comment: MUCH better answer than the ones above. I can't believe anyone is in favor of a no-password admin account.

Answer (score 1):

I see you are still trying to schedule a task on an admin account without a password.

I'm banking on the fact that the only other setting that has to do with blank passwords is the "Limit local account use of blank passwords to console logon only"

Try that setting. It's under Security options, just underneath user right assignments.

Answer (score 0):

There are some restrictions on creating tasks for accounts with blank passwords.

You can create a task which will run shutdown.exe, but you will need to set the "Do not store password" option.  This is on Windows 7 SP1, if you are using a different OS please let us know.

[image: Create Task Window]

For Windows XP, use the command line AT tool:

```
at 23:00 /every:monday,tuesday,wednesday,thursday,friday,saturday,sunday shutdown /s
```

Comment: On Windows XP, sorry. I just updated the question tags to reflect this.

Comment: Answer updated accordingly.